# Cannot run getent command remotely

Tags: linux, networking, centos, linux-networking

On my CentOS 7 machine, I am running this command:

```
pssh -h rephosts -i "/bin/getent hosts sync.$(hostname) | awk '{ print $1 }'"
```

but I am only getting my host ip (where i am executing this command) response from all servers.

I have added entries for hosts in my /etc/hosts file in all machines.

I want all the servers to respond with their ip address respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(hostname)` is evaluated on your local host, before the `pssh` command is started. You can solve this by escaping the `$`:

```
pssh -h rephosts -i "/bin/getent hosts sync.\$(hostname) | awk '{ print \$1 }'"
```

Comment: yes, thanks for the answer. Also I have to put another \ after the print \$1.